# Leading doesn't change the text spacing in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, character

Now that I've changed over to Photoshop CC, I'm having an issue changing the leading. I have two lines of text and I want to put them closer together or farther apart and when I change the leading I can't see anything happening until I tab over or accept the changes. Makes it awfully hard to tell if I have it set correctly! Is this a glitch or is there a setting I need to adjust?

Comment: I use CC2015 and I don't have that problem, it looks more like a glitch. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a screen capture from Photoshop CC (2017).

In this example I show two ways to change the leading. Hopefully one of these might suit your workflow.

1. Simply select the text layer, and click and drag the leading value. However, if you use this method then you can't see the text moving until you release the mouse button.

OR

2. Select the text with the text tool, and click and drag the leading value. Then you will see the text moving as you click and drag the leading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the text to be able to see a preview of the changes you are making.